# The Biggest Step Size with Guaranteed Convergence for Constant Step Size Gradient Descent of a Convex Function with Lipschitz Continuous Gradient

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

Given a convex function $ f \left( x \right) : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R} $ with $ L $ - Lipschitz Continuous Gradient. Namely:

$$ {\left\| \nabla f \left( x \right) - \nabla f \left( y \right) \right\|}_{2} \leq L {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2} $$

What is the largest constant step size, $ \alpha $, one could use in Gradient Descent to minimize the function?
In most literature I see $ \alpha = \frac{1}{L} $ yet in some other cases I see $ \alpha = \frac{2}{L} $. Which one is right?

Also, for the case $ f \left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} $ what is $ L $? Is it the largest Singular Value of $ A $?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $y$ be the one step of gradient descent from $x$, i.e., $y = x-\alpha \nabla f(x)$. Since $f$ is Lipschitz gradient function with constant $L$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(y) - f(x) & \leq \langle \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle + \frac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2 \\
&= -\alpha \|\nabla f(x)\|^2 + \frac{L}{2}\alpha^2\|\nabla f(x)\|^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
To guarantee the sufficient decreasing, we need
\begin{equation}
\frac{L}{2}\alpha^2 - \alpha \leq 0 \Rightarrow \alpha \leq \frac{2}{L}.
\end{equation}
In addition, One can easily find the optimal step size will be $\frac{1}{L}$. 
So if I remember, the step size proving the convergence is $\frac{2}{L}$(c.f. [Boris T. Polyak - Introduction to Optimization](http://www.realsmallass.com/cute/books/math/opt/Polyak87.pdf), Page 21), and the optimal choice is $\frac{1}{L}$(c.f. [Yurii Nesterov - Introductory Lectures on Convex Programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.693.855&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Page 29).

However, even though the gradient descent can converge when $0 < \alpha < \frac{2}{L}$, the convergence rate $O(1/k)$ only could be guaranteed for $0 < \alpha < \frac{1}{L}$
(c.f.[Gradient Descent: Convergence Analysis](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F13/scribes/lec6.pdf), Theorem 6.1).

For $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|^2$, thus
\begin{equation}
\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| = \|A^TA(x-y)\| \leq \|A^TA\| \|x-y\|.
\end{equation}
The inequality is induced by operator norm, i.e., the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$, also the largest singular value of $A$.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank You. Will those derivations hold in case of Projected Gradient Descent?

Comment: Also, could you link to *Introduction to Optimization* and *Introductory Lectures on Convex Programming*?

Comment: I have added the link. For projected gradient descent, I think those derivations still hold.

Comment: But for projected gradient descent,  we could not obtain the convergent rate of $O(1/k)$.

Comment: While I like your answer, I am afraid it only proves that the method converges for all $0<\alpha<\frac{L}{2}$. This is slightly less than showing that $\alpha=\frac{L}{2}$ is the highest possible constant step. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DominikMokriš Your comment is correct, actually we need $0 < \alpha < \frac{2}{L}$. And $\alpha = \frac{2}{L}$ is so called ``largest'' step size but may not converge. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Ze-NanLi What I was wondering was, whether $\alpha=\frac{2}{L}$ is really the highest possible constant step. But Polyak on page 23 gives an example of a function for which the method does not converge with $\alpha=\frac{2}{L}$, which means that you were right.